# Extracting XML Data with SQL

Tags: sql, xml, stored-procedures

I have the following XML data stored in a SQL table

```
<CustomFields xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns="http://www.kaseya.com/vsa/2007/12/ServiceDeskDefinition.xsd">
<Field fieldName="ChangeRequest">No</Field>
<Field fieldName="ProblemRecord">No</Field>
<Field fieldName="Source">Email</Field>
<Field fieldName="KB_Article">No</Field>
<Field fieldName="OptimusRef">264692</Field>
<Field fieldName="TimeSpentOnTicket">0.25</Field>
<Field fieldName="PONumber" />
<Field fieldName="ResourceAssignedEngineer" />
```

What I would like to do is select the TimeSpentOnTicket Value form a stored procedure.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is your XML.  It's invalid, so there's not really a way do search it until you fix it.  A simple way to check this is using an online tool like the [one at W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp).  Another issue that I see is that the namespace (xmlns) that you reference no longer exists.  I think this will mess up Postgres as well, but I'm not 100% on that.  You might to have to filter that out when ingesting.  However, after fixing the XML, it's pretty easy to get things out using [XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx) within the appropriate [XML function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-PROCESSING).

For example, using the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE BLA.TEMPTABLE (ID INT, MYXML XML)
```

Then, insert a valid version of your XML:

```
INSERT INTO BLA.TEMPTABLE ( ID, MYXML )
SELECT 1 as ID, 
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <CustomFields>
        <Field fieldName="ChangeRequest">No</Field>
        <Field fieldName="ProblemRecord">No</Field>
        <Field fieldName="Source">Email</Field>
        <Field fieldName="KB_Article">No</Field>
        <Field fieldName="OptimusRef">264692</Field>
        <Field fieldName="TimeSpentOnTicket">0.25</Field>
        <Field fieldName="PONumber" />
        <Field fieldName="ResourceAssignedEngineer" />
    </CustomFields>' as MYXML
```

Then, to query it back out, you can do something like the following (you can test your XPath with a tool like [this](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath), if you need to):

```
SELECT
    tt.ID, 
    tt.MYXML,
    XPATH('/CustomFields//Field[@fieldName=''TimeSpentOnTicket'']/text()', tt.MYXML)
FROM
    BLA.TEMPTABLE tt
```

Comment: By the way, the XPATH returns an array, so if you need just the first value in the array, you can do something like the following `SELECT ID, MYXML, (XPATH('/CustomFields//Field[@fieldName=''TimeSpentOnTicket'']/text()', MYXML))[1] FROM BLA.TEMPTABLE`